# How does Open MPI implement datatype conversion?

Tags: mpi, communication, openmpi

MPI standard states that when parallel programs are running on heterogenerous environment, they may have different representations for a same datatype(like big endian and small endian machines for intergers), so datatype representation conversion might be needed when doing point to point communication. I don't know how Open MPI implements this.

For instance, current Open MPI uses UCX library defaultly, I have study some codes of UCX library and Open MPI's ucx module. However, for continuous datatype like MPI_INT, I didn't find any representation conversion happen. I wonder is it because I miss that part or the implementation didn't satisfy the standard?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run an Open MPI app on an heterogeneous cluster, you have to `configure --enable-heterogeneous` (this is disabled by default). Keep in mind this is supposed to work, but it is lightly tested, mainly because of a lack of interest/real use cases. FWIW, IBM Power is now little endian, and Fujitsu is moving from Sparc to ARM for HPC, so virtually all HPC processors are (or will soon be) little endian.

Open MPI uses convertors (see `opal/datatype/opal_convertor.h`) to pack the data before sending it, and unpack it once received.
The data is packed in its current endianness. Data conversion (e.g. swap bytes) is performed by the receiver if the sender has a different endianness.

There are two ways of using UCX : `pml/ucx` and `pml/ob1+btl/ucx` and I have tested none of them in a heterogeneous environment. If you are facing some issues with `pml/ucx`, try `mpirun --mca pml ob1 ...`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am not working on a heterogenerous environment, just be curious about this part. Anyway, I guess this is not an import issue for today's HPC anymore.